# Can I program eSIM/eUICC devices with Java Applets

Tags: mobile, smartcard, javacard, sim-card, lte

From my research on embedded SIM (eSIM) technology, it's a SIM card that the consumer owns and is capable of downloading and switching between 3rd party subscriptions.  I've also read it's expected that most eSIMs will run a Java Runtime and support Java applets [1].

Is it possible to program Java applets onto eSIMs, similar to programming a Java smart card?

[1] "EUICC45", https://www.gsma.com/newsroom/wp-content/uploads/SGP.21_v2.1.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The active [specification](https://www.gsma.com/newsroom/resources/sgp-22-technical-specification-v2-2-1/).

> 2.4.11.1 Java Card packages An eUICC supporting Java CardTM SHALL support the Java Packages listed below. The implementation of each
>   Package SHALL as a minimum be according to the given Package version
>   and Specification version

Then a list of the supported packages

Comment: Of course, you'd need the keys to authenticate to the (e)SIM, so it very likely depends on the network provider and possibly manufacturer as well.